# WebMatrix WebSecurity: Keeps logging out user randomly

Tags: session, authentication, security, webmatrix

I'm using WebMatrix and applied a login system on my website. I'm running into a strange problem. My website keeps randomly logging out the user. Happens unexpectedly. Not only on my code, but happens in the WebMatrix sample projects as well.

My Web.Config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/login" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <sessionState timeout="20" />
    <!-- This is for links with incorrect file extensions -->
    <!-- This only handles .NET based errors, not classic web like HTML or ASP based extensions -->
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Shared/Error404.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Shared/Error404.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Shared/Error500.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- This handles all other types of link errors -->
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Shared/Error404.cshtml" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

I've defined the session timeout as 20 minutes. I use the same plain way of logging in the user.

```
    if (WebSecurity.Login(email, password, rememberMe)) {
        Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
        return;
    } else {
        ModelState.AddFormError("The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
```

And this is how I check whether my user is signed-in or not in secured pages:

```
if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    Response.Redirect("~/login", true);
}
```

I've searched a bit on google, there are few people who have also been complaining that WebMatrix WebSecurity randomly logs out user. Sometimes when an activity is performed, like form submission or sometimes a simple url click.

Any ideas or suggestions? Someone even suggested me to dump Razor and move to MVC, it doesn't have this problem. I'm not sure whether thats true.

**UPDATE**

I have the following code in top of all my secured pages (which require user being logged in). Does anyone think this would be causing the issue?

```
// Ensure this page is not cached    
Response.Expires = -1;
Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Thanks
-Faraz Azhar

Comment: I'm using webMatrix in a production environment.  Currently there are 60 users logged in, so it's no a WebMatrix issue.

Comment: Do you use session expiry or no server cache? Please see my post again, I've written an update on it.

Comment: The vast majority of my pages don't have any Response. calls at all.  I only check WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated at the top of pages that need to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

I will have to check further, i remember some weirdo setting to increase the cookie stay-logged-in time.  Here's what's in my config and i don't see anything else that has a time:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/error/"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication>
      <forms timeout="10080" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: I've already tried this out as well. It appears to be some cookie issue, no doubt. The session kinda gets expired or something. Sometimes after few seconds, sometimes after many minutes. Its going just random.

Comment: It's nothing to do with session timeout. Knox is right - you need to increase the forms timeout value.

Comment: That's what everyone keeps telling. I've already setup session timeout with 20 minutes and forms timeout to 10080. Makes no difference.